# How to require some lib files from anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

I'll explain my situation.

Here is my file tree in my rails application :

lib/my_module.rb

```
require 'my_module/my_file'

module My_module

end
```

lib/my_module/my_file.rb

```
class Tweetag::Collector
   (...)
end
```

I've made a ruby script that I've put in config/jobs/

I really don't understand how I am supposed to require the file my_file.rb in this file.

```
require '../../my_module/my_file.rb'
```

It gives me  `require': cannot load such file

Same error with just require 'my_module' which is what I do in my controllers...

Someone here to explain to me ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 33):

You can autoinclude everything under the lib `folder`and avoid these problems:

Type this your file in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: I did it, but still :

`<main>': uninitialized constant MyModule (NameError)

Comment: now include your module where you need it, with `include My_module`

Comment: you declared `My_module` but you are using `MyModule`. Fix this inconsistency. However the convention is to use `MyModule` form for the modules you define

Comment: Well actually you can replace all the "my_module" by "Tweetag" and all the "my_file" by "Collector".

I tried to be generic in my explanations but I failed.

Anyways, when I do "include Tweetag", it doesn't work.

Comment: have you restarted your application server, so that the config file is read?

Comment: On production server with Rails 5.2.2 you might need to use `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Answer (score 24):

If you want to require only a specific file then,
do something relative to Rails root like this

```
for example: --

lib/plan.rb

module Plan
 ...some code...
end
```

and if you want to require it only in some model, say app/models/user.rb

do in user model

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/plan"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Plan
end
```

if you want it to be available everywhere

one solution is given by @VecchiaSpugna

or you can create a ruby file in config/initializers folder

and require all file over there one by one

OR

```
try this

require '../../my_module/my_file'

instead of 

require '../../my_module/my_file.rb'
```

You don't need to specify extension for a file in require.

Comment: Well actually I just understood that I cannot do something specific to rails as you just said.

I juste would like to run the command line "ruby my_ruby_script.rb" and require my lib module in it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to do `require Rails.root.join('lib', 'plan')`?

Answer (score 7):

I think there are two solutions.

1) Add the lib path to the search path.
In ruby:

```
$:.unshift('../../my_module/lib')
```

Then you can `require 'my_module.rb'`

I think [Vecchia Spugna answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17951538/676874) is the rails-version of my ruby-answer. (I'm not familiar with rails).

2) Another solution:

In your `lib/my_module.rb` you require `my_file`. This file is located relative to your `my_module.rb`? Then use `require_relative`:

```
require_relative './my_module/my_file'
```

Comment: 1) is the way to go, since the job in config/jobs seems not to be started from within his rails application. Therefore he must setup the load path himself as you describe it rather than expecting, that a not used rails environment will do this for him.

Answer (score 1):

Just chiming in because it took me forever to figure this out because very little solutions worked.

• I had to use plain old require. I put it in the `config/application.rb` file.

`patching_file_path = File.expand_path("./lib", Dir.pwd)
 Dir[patching_file_path+'/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }`

• I also put a temporary `puts "I'm Working!` in the file I'm trying to require so I can check the console to see if it's actually loading.

• Also, if you're using spring loader, before you start your console you should do `bin/spring stop` in your terminal before you start your rails console. Otherwise, it won't load new files.

Comment: I was also stuck with this for a while. Stopping Spring did the trick for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to require_relative,

```
# inside lib/my_module.rb 
require File.expand_path('./my_module/my_file', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

This expands the path of current file directory and add the relative file path to be required.